# Create Unique Sequence in MySQL Community Server

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create stored procedure in MySQL Community Server 5.5.16:

```
CREATE UNIQUE SEQUENCE seq_num_accountnumber;

Create Procedure usp_createCustomerAccount(IN pCustomer INTEGER,pCredit INTEGER)
NOT DETERMINISTIC
MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN
DECLARE Z INTEGER;
set Z = NEXT_VALUE OF seq_num_accountnumber;
if pCredit is null then
Insert into Account(Number,Customer,Credit) Values(Z,pCustomer,0);
else
Insert into Account(Number,Customer,Credit) Values(Z,pCustomer,pCredit);
End if;
End
```

But I do not know how to use UNIQUE SEQUENCE in MySQL Server. I tried like this but I think it is incorrect because the value is not unique:

```
Create Procedure my_createCustomerAccount(IN pCustomer INTEGER,pCredit INTEGER)
NOT DETERMINISTIC
MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN
DECLARE Z INTEGER;
set Z = 1;
if pCredit is null then
Insert into Account(Number,Customer,Credit) Values(Z,pCustomer,0);
else
Insert into Account(Number,Customer,Credit) Values(Z,pCustomer,pCredit);
set Z = Z+1;
End if;
End
```

Comment: MySQL does not support sequences

Comment: Is there any reason not to use  `AUTO_INCREMENT column`?

Comment: I don't know how to use AUTO_INCREMENT in stored procedure and make it unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just set the field `Number as NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT` and in the insert sql `INSERT INTO Account(Customer, Credit) VALUES(pCustomer,0);`